# Vue Directive not updating it's value - Jquery Chosen

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vuejs2, jquery-chosen

I am using Jquery Chosen along with Vue. This is my Vue directive:

```
Vue.component("chosen-select", {
    props: {
        value: [String, Array],
        multiple: Boolean
    },
    template: `<select :multiple="multiple"><slot></slot></select>`,
    mounted() {
        $(this.$el)
            .val(this.value)
            .chosen({ width: '100%' })
            .on("change", e => this.$emit('input', $(this.$el).val()))
    },
    watch: {
        value(val) {
            $(this.$el).val(val).trigger('chosen:updated');
        }
    },
    destroyed() {
        $(this.$el).chosen('destroy');
    }
});
```

And using it like this:

```
<chosen-select v-model="basicDetailsModel.stateID" v-validate="'required'" data-vv-as="state" :state="errors.has('stateID') ? 'invalid' : 'valid'" name="stateID">
                        <option :value="null">Please select an option</option>
                        <option v-for="(state, index) in states" :key="index" :value="state.sid">{{state.nm}}</option>
                    </chosen-select>
```

If the states are assigned static value it works fine as per expectation but if I fetch the states value dynamically the chosen is not updated with latest values. It stays with the initial values.

How would I fix this issue?

**Edit:** This one works. Do you think this is the right way?

```
Vue.component("chosen-select", {
    data() {
        return { observer: null }
    },
    props: {
        value: [String, Array],
        multiple: Boolean
    },
    template: `<select :multiple="multiple"><slot></slot></select>`,
    mounted() {
        // Create the observer (and what to do on changes...)
        this.observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
            $(this.$el).trigger("chosen:updated");
        }.bind(this));

        // Setup the observer
        this.observer.observe(
            $(this.$el)[0],
            { childList: true }
        );
        $(this.$el)
            .val(this.value)
            .chosen({ width: '100%' })
            .on("change", e => this.$emit('input', $(this.$el).val()))
    },
    watch: {
        value(val) {
            $(this.$el).val(val);
        }
    },
    destroyed() {
        $(this.$el).chosen('destroy');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to fix this issue is simply not to render the select until you have options to render using `v-if`.

```
<chosen-select v-if="states && states.length > 0" v-model="basicDetailsModel.stateID" v-validate="'required'" data-vv-as="state" :state="errors.has('stateID') ? 'invalid' : 'valid'" name="stateID">
```

You could also play around with emitting the `chosen:updated` event when the component is updated.

```
updated(){
  $(this.$el).trigger("chosen:updated")
},
```

which works for multiple selects, but mysteriously not for single selects.

Comment: I initially tried that updated worked but may be inefficient as updated is called each time even v-model's attribute changed (select change occurred). I found some inspiration from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38148297/in-vue-js-can-a-component-detect-when-the-slot-content-changes and accordingly changed my code. See my edit in question. Let me know how it is.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure how you are fetching the states dynamically, but if you're using jQuery to get them, then I think that is your problem. Vue doesn't get notified if non-Vue things (like jQuery) change anything.
Even if that's not the case, [this](https://medium.com/js-dojo/how-to-safely-use-a-jquery-plugin-with-vue-js-786acdfb743b) is worth reading to see why jQuery and Vue don't get along.
Can you add how you are fetching them dynamically?
Also, consider using a Vue framework like [Vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com/) which has a pretty good select control and is totally in Vue.