# Determining if slot content is null or empty

Tags: vue.js

I have a little Loading component, whose default text I want to be 'Loading...'. Good candidate for slots, so I have something like this as my template:

`<p class="loading"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i><slot>Loading...</slot></p>`

That allows me to change the loading message with e.g. `<loading>Searching...</loading>`. The behaviour I would like, though, is not just to display the default message if no slot content is supplied, but also if the slot content is null or blank. At the moment if I do e.g.`<loading>{{loadingMessage}}</loading>` and loadingMessage is null, no text is displayed (where I want the default text to be displayed). So ideally I need to test `this.$slots.default`. This tells me whether content was passed in, but how do I find whether or not it was empty? `this.$slots.default.text` returns undefined.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You'd need a computed property which checks for `this.$slots`. With a default slot you'd check `this.$slots.default`, and with a named slot just replace `default` with the slot name.

```
computed: {
  slotPassed() {
    return !!this.$slots.default[0].text.length
  }
}
```

And then use it in your template:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <slot v-if="slotPassed">Loading...</slot>
    <p v-else>Searching...</p>
  </div>
</template>
```

You can see a small example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/oq056vo8zz). Notice how fallback content is displayed and not "default content", which is inside the slot.

---

**Edit**:
My wording could've been better. What you **need** to do is check for `$slots.X` value, but computed property is **a way** to check that. You could also just write the slot check in your template:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <slot v-if="!!$slots.default[0].text">Loading...</slot>
    <p v-else>Searching...</p>
  </div>
</template>
```

---

**Edit 2**: As pointed out by @GoogleMac in the comments, checking for a slot's text property fails for renderless components (e.g. `<transition>`, `<keep-alive>`, ...), so the check they suggested is:

```
!!this.$slots.default && !!this.$slots.default[0]

// or..
!!(this.$slots.default || [])[0]
```

Comment: The problem I'm seeing is that `$slots.default.text` is always undefined. Here's a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/JohnMoore/rmafyz2x/2/

Comment: My bad, `$slots.default` is an array, so the thing you need is `$slots.default[0].text` : )

Comment: Yes, that's the answer I've been looking for. As long as I can test for `$slots.default[0].text` I can achieve what I want.

Comment: For me, there was a slot passed, but the above answer still failed because the slot was a Vue `<transition>` element with another element inside. The transition element has a text property of `undefined`. In my case I have a computed property which returns `!!this.$slots.default && !!this.$slots.default[0]`.

Comment: @GoogleMac aha, a TIL-moment for me! Thanks for sharing, I've edited my answer to include your insight

Answer (score 6):

@kano's answer works well, but there's a gotcha: `this.$slots` isn't reactive, so if it starts out being `false`, and then becomes `true`, any `computed` property won't update.

The solution is to not rely on a `computed` value but instead on `created` and `beforeUpdated` ([as @MathewSonke points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55763337/827129)):

```js
export default {
  name: "YourComponentWithDynamicSlot",
  data() {
    return {
      showFooter: false,
      showHeader: false,
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.setShowSlots();
  },
  beforeUpdate() {
    this.setShowSlots();
  },
  methods: {
    setShowSlots() {
      this.showFooter = this.$slots.footer?.[0];
      this.showHeader = this.$slots.header?.[0];
    },
  },
};
```

### UPDATE: Vue 3 (Composition API)

For Vue 3, it seems that the way to check whether a slot has content has changed (using the new composition API):

```js
import { computed, defineComponent } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
  setup(_, { slots }) {
    const showHeader = computed(() => !!slots.header);

    return {
      showHeader,
    };
  },
});
```

*note: I can't find any documentation on this, so take it with a pinch of salt, but seems to work in my very limited testing.*

Comment: For Vue 2, if you're using scoped slots, the reference is actually a function, not an object. So you have to execute it before checking for child elements. `const scopedSlot = this.$scopedSlots.myScopedSlot; const scopedSlotResolved = scopedSlot(); const hasChild = !!(scopedSlotResolved?.[0]);` Can then do a null check, since the scoped slot reference won't be a function until later in the lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

`this.$slots` can be checked to see if a slot has been used.

It is important to note that `this.$slots` is not reactive. This could cause problems when using `this.$slots` in a computed value.

[https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/?redirect=true#:~:text=Please%20note%20that%20slots%20are%20not%20reactive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/?redirect=true#:%7E:text=Please%20note%20that%20slots%20are%20not%20reactive).

This means we need to ensure that `this.slots` is checked whenever the component re-renders. We can do this simply by using a method instead of a computed property.

[https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html?redirect=true#:~:text=In%20comparison%2C%20a%20method%20invocation%20will%20always%20run%20the%20function%20whenever%20a%20re%2Drender%20happens](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html?redirect=true#:%7E:text=In%20comparison%2C%20a%20method%20invocation%20will%20always%20run%20the%20function%20whenever%20a%20re%2Drender%20happens)

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <slot v-if="hasHeading" name="heading"/>
    </div>
</template>


<script>
export default{
    name: "some component",
    methods: {
        hasHeading(){ return !!this.slots.heading}
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Can we safely reduce <slot v-if="hasHeading" .../> to <slot v-if="!!$slots.heading" .../>, and bypass creating a method?